# Why getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, multithreading

Giving me correct output but sometime getting IndexOutOFBound Exception.....Not able to get what reordering is done by the compiler?

```
package com.array.thread;

import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class EvenOddProcessor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(6, new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("BARRIER BROKEN!!!");

            }
        });

        int[] array = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            array[i] = i;

        ArrayIndexProcessor evenIndexProcessor = new ArrayIndexProcessor(array,
                0, barrier);
        ArrayIndexProcessor oddIndexProcessor = new ArrayIndexProcessor(array,
                1, barrier);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(evenIndexProcessor, "Even_1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(evenIndexProcessor, "Even_2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(evenIndexProcessor, "Even_3");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        Thread t4 = new Thread(oddIndexProcessor, "Odd_1");
        Thread t5 = new Thread(oddIndexProcessor, "Odd_2");
        Thread t6 = new Thread(oddIndexProcessor, "Odd_3");
        t4.start();
        t5.start();
        t6.start();

        System.out.println(">>>>>  Main thread is done");

    }
}

class ArrayIndexProcessor implements Runnable {

    private final CyclicBarrier barrier;

    private final int[] array;

    private volatile int currentPtr = 0;

    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public ArrayIndexProcessor(int[] array, int startIndex,
            CyclicBarrier barrier) {
        this.array = array;
        this.currentPtr = startIndex;
        this.barrier = barrier;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            barrier.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!(array.length == 0) && (currentPtr < array.length)) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "="
                        + array[currentPtr]);
                currentPtr = currentPtr + 2;
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A full stack trace, with pointers to lines mentioned in it, would be much appreciated (and prevent the forthcoming closing of your question).

Comment: When asking for help with an exception, quote the full text of the exception, and tell us which line in the codeblock is the one the exception refers to.

Answer (score 5):

```
    while (!(array.length == 0) && (currentPtr < array.length)) {
        lock.lock();
```

You first make the bounds-check on `currentPtr`, then lock, then use `currentPtr` as array index. Since you are reusing the same `Runnable` instance across three threads, `currentPtr` may have been modified in the meantime, resulting in an out-of-bounds index.